# HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found (how to call wcf service from jquery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, wcf, razor

i am trying to call my WCF method from MVC(razor) using jquery then i am getting an error

1. Request URL: localhost:8377/Service/ajaxServiceEstimate.svc/Location
2. Request Method: POST Status
3. Code: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

**Web Config**

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Estimate.Service.ajaxServiceEstimate" behaviorConfiguration="Estimate.Service.ajaxServiceEstimate" >
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Estimate.Service.ajaxServiceEstimateAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Estimate.Service.ajaxServiceEstimate" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Estimate.Service.ajaxServiceEstimateAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Estimate.Service.ajaxServiceEstimate" >
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Service Code**

```
    namespace Estimate.Service
{
    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class ajaxServiceEstimate
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public void DoWork()
        {
            // Add your operation implementation here
            return;
        }

        // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public string Location()
        {
            return "anurag";
        }
    }
}
```

**jQuery Code :**

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetTeamData() {
        $.ajax(
        {
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://localhost:8377/Service/ajaxServiceEstimate.svc/Location",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '{}',
            success: function (content) {
                DisplayRun(map, content);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<div>
    <input id="btnSave" type="button" value="Save" onclick="GetTeamData();" />
    <div id="divOutput"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you resolve localhost:8377/Service/ajaxServiceEstimate.svc/Location at all, in any context?

Comment: Hi NWard,  i tried "~/Service/ajaxServiceEstimate.svc/Location" this one and "../Service/ajaxServiceEstimate.svc/Location" this one

Answer (score 0):

Is there any compulsory of using WCF. Better use WebAPI they are quite simple and fast. WCF creates problems if stuck in a bindings. Try using WebAPI if you can.

Comment: It is a possible comment!

Comment: thanks for reply ,
actually i have to create application in MVC(razor) and call to WCF from jQuery it's requirement

Answer (score 0):

You should check your routing file, and set Services folder to be ignored.
Also add file type to be accepted.

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathInfo}", new { folder = "Service" });
```

For more information
   http://forums.asp.net/t/1970859.aspx?Problem+Calling+WCF+Service+Library+from+jQuery+